# Apache: extensionless URLs get an automatic .php extension

Tags: apache-2.2

When I ask the server for an URL which has no extension, but is not a directory, apache automatically adds a .php extension to it. Where is this behavior configured?

EDIT: I'm sorry, my question wasn't clear: I'm not asking how to do this, I just found out that my local server (Apache/2.2.11 on Debian) does it by itself (i.e. I have no rewrite rules) and I wanted to know where this can be configured.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Debian (speaking current versions as you mention Apache 2.2.11 which falls somewhere between Lenny and Sid) has the `MultiViews` option enabled for `/var/www` and `/usr/share/doc` directories by default in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default`. With this option enabled Apache will attempt to match a URI request to any file with an extension it knows about. That said if the URI is requesting `/test` it will attempt things like `test.php`, `test.html`, `test.txt`, etc until it finds a match.

Comment: Thanks that was it! Didn't upvote just cause I can't :)

Answer (score 0):

There's a few ways to do this.  I'd use a mod_rewrite approach:

- let any url ending in .php (.jpg, etc) pass through, last rule if match
- rewrite the URL to end in .php, last rule if match